# nvidia-docker GPU in Docker Container

Tags: docker, tensorflow, nvidia-docker

I'm trying to replicate work/experiments which require me to follow [this particular tutorial on setting up Jupyter + Tensorflow + Nvidia GPU + Docker + Google Compute Engine](https://medium.com/google-cloud/jupyter-tensorflow-nvidia-gpu-docker-google-compute-engine-4a146f085f17). '

I'm able to successfully install `nvidia-docker`. However, in the [tutorial](https://medium.com/google-cloud/jupyter-tensorflow-nvidia-gpu-docker-google-compute-engine-4a146f085f17), under the section `Verify the GPU is Visible from a Docker Container`, when I try to run

```
sudo nvidia-docker-plugin
```

I get the following error (see last line):

```
nvidia-docker-plugin | 2019/04/23 15:17:47 Loading NVIDIA unified memory
nvidia-docker-plugin | 2019/04/23 15:17:47 Loading NVIDIA management library
nvidia-docker-plugin | 2019/04/23 15:17:47 Discovering GPU devices
nvidia-docker-plugin | 2019/04/23 15:17:47 Provisioning volumes at /var/lib/nvidia-docker/volumes
nvidia-docker-plugin | 2019/04/23 15:17:47 Serving plugin API at /run/docker/plugins
nvidia-docker-plugin | 2019/04/23 15:17:47 Serving remote API at localhost:3476
nvidia-docker-plugin | 2019/04/23 15:17:47 Error: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:3476: bind: address already in use
```

And when I run

```
sudo nvidia-docker run --rm nvidia/cuda nvidia-smi
```

I happen to get the following `executable file not found in $PATH": unknown` error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"nvidia-smi\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

I'm pretty new to docker; thus it would be nice if someone could help walk me through the solution. I've tried searching [for answers](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/388), but the actual process for solving the problem evades me. Any help would be highly appreciated.

EDIT: I set the GCE instance as specified in the tutorial (i.e. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, 50GB boot disk, 1 GPU, with jupyter and tensorboard)

Comment: Regarding the nvidia docker plugin address in use, you might have already have one instance running. Can you try running the docker with `docker run --runtime=nvidia --rm nvidia/cuda:9.0-base nvidia-smi` (perhaps sudo is needed)? The new nvidia-docker is integrated with the docker engine as a runtime.

Comment: @FrankYuchengGu Running the said command returns `docker: Error response from daemon: Unknown runtime specified nvidia.`

Comment: Are you able to run `nvidia-docker` at all? Have you tried the PATH fix specified in the answer link you included?

Comment: @FrankYuchengGu No, as I'm not entirely sure how to go about this. Could you perhaps point me to a resource that would explain how to do this more clearly?

Answer (score 3):

To solve the first, looks like nvidia-docker-plugin is already running. To find this service, use :

```
sudo netstat -tlpn | grep 3476
```

And kill it with :

```
sudo pkill nvidia-docker
```

The second, install nvidia-docker2 and reload the Docker daemon configuration with :

```
curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/gpgkey | \
  sudo apt-key add -
distribution=$(. /etc/os-release;echo $ID$VERSION_ID)
curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/$distribution/nvidia-docker.list | \
  sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-docker.list
sudo apt-get update

# Install nvidia-docker2 and reload the Docker daemon configuration
sudo apt-get install -y nvidia-docker2
sudo pkill -SIGHUP dockerd
```

Links for more details :

- https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/301
- https://medium.com/@sh.tsang/docker-tutorial-5-nvidia-docker-2-0-installation-in-ubuntu-18-04-cb80f17cac65